# Reverse of `__getitem___`

Tags: python, dictionary

`d[x]` where `d` is a dict, invokes `d.__getitem__(x)`. Is there a way to create a class `F`, so that `y=F(X); d[y]` would invoke some method in `F` instead: `y.someMethod(d)`?

Background: I'm trying to make a dict with "aliased" keys, so that if I have `d[a]=42`, then `d[alias_of_a]` would return 42 as well. This is pretty straightforward with the custom `__getitem__`, for example:

```
class oneOf(object):
    def __init__(self, *keys):
        self.keys = keys

class myDict(dict):
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        if isinstance(item, oneOf):
            for k in item.keys:
                if k in self:
                    return self[k]
        return dict.__getitem__(self, item)


a = myDict({
    'Alpha': 1,
    'B': 2,
})

print a[oneOf('A', 'Alpha')]
print a[oneOf('B', 'Bravo')]
```

However, I'm wondering if it could be possible without overriding `dict`:

```
a = {
    'Alpha': 1,
    'B': 2,
}

print a[???('A', 'Alpha')]
print a[???('B', 'Bravo')]
```

If this is not possible, how to make it work the other way round:

```
a = {
    ???('A', 'Alpha'): 1,
    ???('B', 'Bravo'): 2,
}

print a['A']
print a['Bravo']
```

What it important to me is that I'd like to avoid extending `dict`.

Comment: No, there is no such method. Objects being passed into `__getitem__` are not notified of such use.

Comment: You can make your keys *equivalent* by mapping to a canonical value, then using `__eq__` and `__hash__` to slot to the same dictionary hash table slot. But that requires that you have a method to map to a canonical.

Comment: You might be interested in [PEP-455](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0455/), which has not yet been accepted but appears applicable to your use case.

Comment: @chepner: thanks, interesting, although this is basically the same as the snippet #1, i.e. overriding `dict`. I'm trying to achieve the same with genuine dicts.

Comment: The fact that `TransformDict` is being considered strongly implies you cannot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This use-case is impossible:

```
a = {
    'Alpha': 1,
    'B': 2,
}

a[???('A', 'Alpha')]
a[???('B', 'Bravo')]
```

This is because the `dict` will first hash the object. In order to force a collision, which will allow overriding equality to take hold, the hashes need to match. But `???('A', 'Alpha')` can only hash to *one* of `'A'` or `'Alpha'`, and if it makes the wrong choice it has failed.

The other use-case has a similar deduction applied to it:

```
a = {
    ???('A', 'Alpha'): 1,
    ???('B', 'Bravo'): 2,
}

a['A']
a['Bravo']
```

`a['A']` will look up with a different hash to `a['Alpha']`, so again `???('A', 'Alpha')` needs to have both hashes, which is impossible.

You need cooperation from *both* the keys and the values in order for this to work.

---

You could in theory use `inspect.getouterframes` in the `__hash__` method to check the values of the dictionary, but this would only work if dictionaries *had* Python frames. If your intent is to monkey patch a function that sort-of does what you want but not quite, this might (just about) work(ish, sort of).

```
import inspect

class VeryHackyAnyOfHack:
    def __init__(self, variable_name_hack, *args):
        self.variable_name_hack = variable_name_hack
        self.equal_to = args

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return other in self.equal_to

    def __hash__(self):
        outer_frame = inspect.getouterframes(inspect.currentframe())[1]

        assumed_target_dict = outer_frame[0].f_locals[self.variable_name_hack]

        for item in self.equal_to:
            if item in assumed_target_dict:
                return hash(item)

        # Failure
        return hash(item[0])
```

This is used like so:

```
import random

def check_thing_agains_dict(item):
    if random.choice([True, False]):
        internal_dict = {"red": "password123"}
    else:
        internal_dict = {"blue": "password123"}

    return internal_dict[item]

myhack = VeryHackyAnyOfHack('internal_dict', "red", "blue")
check_thing_agains_dict(myhack)
#>>> 'password123'
```

Again, the very fact that you have to do this means that in practice it's not possible. It's also a language extension, so this isn't portable.

Comment: I was thinking along the same line (make a decorator that parses ast or bytecode etc), but it's clearly not worth it.

Answer (score 1):

The built-in `dict` provides very simple lookup semantics: given a hashable object `x`, return the object `y` that `x` was mapped to previously. If you want multiple keys that map to the same object, you'll need to set that up explicitly:

```
# First, initialize the dictionary with one key per equivalence class
a = { 'a': 1, 'b': 2 }
# Then, set up any aliases.
a['Alpha'] = a['a']
a['Bravo'] = a['b']
```

The `TransformDict` class being considered for inclusion in Python 3.5 would simplify this somewhat by allowing you to replace step 2 with a "secondary" lookup function that would map the given key to its canonical representation prior to the primary lookup. Something like

```
def key_transform(key):
    if key in {'Alpha', 'Aleph'}:
        return 'a'
    elif key in {'Bravo', 'Beta', 'Beth'}:
        return 'b'

a = TransformDict(key_transform, a=1, b=2)
assert a['Alpha'] is a['a']
```

Comment: Thanks! `TransformDict` looks interesting.